# Ruby on Rails call an action I created

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, action

I have in my User view `Index` page a `button_to` tag as follows:

`<%= button_to "Make Admin", :action => :make_admin :user => user %>`

In the User controller i have:

`def make_admin

    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    @changed_user.role = 3

    @changed_user.save

end`

I get a message about bad routing, but since I'm not interested in changing the view until after the action I don't know how to route this action. Where have i gone wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to name the path in your routes:

```
# routes.rb
get 'your_path' => 'user#make_admin, :as => 'make_admin' # can use post too
```

```
# controller
def make_admin
  # logic to make an admin
  redirect_to(some_other_path, :notice => 'User was made an admin')
end
```

then, in your view,

```
button_to 'make admin', make_admin_path
```

You might also want to make the call remotely, but you'll need to post another question with more information in that sense

Comment: What path? the action doesn't have a specific page to go to i just want the action to happen.

Comment: You still need to define a route to that action. A route specifies the action you want to render in your controller... look above, Ive added some more. In your action, you'll need to redirect properly then

Comment: I'm still having some trouble waht would be the apth for example that i would put instead of 'your_path' the page that the button sits on?

Comment: whatever url you want... it doesn't really matter if its always going to be redirected... it can be 'admin', 'make_admin', 'foo_bar', 'fajkdlfjakljr4jkla'. its what the server actually posts/gets for the request